# Google Cloud Pub/Sub Pull PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have Google Cloud SDK in my local machine, and when I run the command:

```
gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull --auto-ack MY_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME
```

It works just fine and I can see the messages.

But, if I do the same thing in the GCE VM I created, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.pubsub.subscriptions.pull) PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.
```

I've tried several things already, like:

- Stop the instance and add a Service Account;
- Make my instance "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs";
- Do `sudo yum update google-cloud-sdk`

I don't know what else to try to make it work. Any ideas? Please give me a light here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should go to the [Cloud console subscriptions page](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/subscriptions) and ensure that your service account has the "Pub/Sub Subscriber" permission on the subscription. When you are on the subscriptions page, you can click the check box next to the subscription and then the following will appear on the right of the screen:

[image: Permission Section]

Ensure that your service account is in the circled section and if it is not, add it. To do so, type in the service account under "Add members" and in the "Select a role" dropdown, choose "Pub/Sub Subscriber" and then click the "Add" button. Note that to add the service account, you will need to be logged into the Cloud console with an account that has the Owner or Pub/Sub Admin per the [Pub/Sub access control rules](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access_control#tbl_roles).

This is not the same as selecting "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs." That feature indicates which APIs the GCE instance can acccess; it does not affect the authentication of the service account for accessing the desired resource (e.g, subscription) through those APIs.

It is likely that this worked through the gcloud command line tool because you were authenticated with the Google account that was used to create the subscription.

Comment: Could you check the link you put on the answer? It is taking me to a very weird page. Doesn't look like Google stuff.

Comment: Apologies, that was the internal version of the link. I have fixed it.

Comment: My account is not in the circled section. But I can't add it, it says I don't have the permissions. The only permission I have is 'Editor'. But that does not explain why I am able to access it from my local machine but not from a GCE VM instance that I created

Comment: The reason why you can access it from your local machine but not the GCE VM is probably that you are authenticated with a different account on each. On your local machine, you are probably authenticated with your personal account. On the GCE VM, you are likely authenticated via the service account. The reason you can't add the service account is that the account you use to log into the Cloud console needs to have the Owner or Pub/Sub Admin role to update permissions on a subscription. I have added some more details in my answer to mention this fact.

Comment: Man, that was super helpful. The thing that was bugging me the most was how could be possible to get it from my local machine but not from the GCE VM. After your comments and answer I checked and you were correct, I was using two different accounts in the different machines. I didn't realized I had two accounts, I though all authorization I was creating was under the same root account, but it was not. I then used the command ```gcloud auth login``` on my VM and logged with my account. It is working just fine now! Thanks again for the support

Comment: Basically service account creating with adequate permissions are not enough. We have to add the same service account in Pub/Sub permissions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some times you just need to implement a provide class to set autorization like CustomCredentialsProvider -> take a look at google documentation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).