# Giving GCP service account Pub/Sub rights for topic in different project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authorization, google-cloud-pubsub, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

I have a Node.js service running in GCP VM, running as a service account. Now I want to subscribe to a Pub/Sub topic. The Service account and the VM belong to Project A, the topic belongs to Project B.

I'm always getting Error: `7 PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action`.

What I have tried:

- Adding `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub` to the scopes when creating the template of the VM. Seeing now `Cloud Pub/Sub: Enabled` in the `API and identity management` section of the instance. So, that seems to have worked.
- Giving the service account the `roles/pubsub.subscriber` role via command `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project --member="serviceAccount:my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role='roles/pubsub.subscriber'`
- Giving the service account the "Pub/Sub subscriber" role in Project B:

[image]

- Giving the service account access to the topic itself:

[image]

But still, the error is the same.

(Side note: If a GCP manager reads this: The GCP logs don't show any details. That's not helpful in this case. If you need four permissions to run something then I expect the logs to be like `You need 4 permissions, your user has permission A, C, D, but lacking B` and not just `User not authorized to perform this action.`)

Comment: Does this [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623509/) and [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463869/) solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

can you try `my-project-b` with a service accont from the `my-project-a` -

slightly modified your code:

`gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project-b --member="serviceAccount:my-sa@my-project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role='roles/pubsub.subscriber'`

and so on...

Comment: Didn't work for me. And I think that it should be the same as `Giving the service account the "Pub/Sub subscriber" role in Project B` via the GUI (as mentioned above). What would be the difference? The reason why I've ran this as a command is that I haven't found such a thing in the GUI for the project A (which is the one owning the service account).

Comment: well... it always worked for me. However, I've never tried such things through UI; tried only command line or terraform.

Answer (score 0):

What's your error? Is the error from "trying to create a subscription", or "trying to connect to a subscription and consume message"?

The former needs more permissions than Subscriber: projects.subscriptions.create

Subscriber can only consumer message, but not creating a new subscription: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#pubsub.subscriber

Comment: As you can read in my question, the action I'm trying to do i is `Now I want to subscribe to a Pub/Sub topic`. Nothing about creating it. Furthermore, I'm aware of the `roles/pubsub.subscriber` and I've tried to use that one.

Comment: Have you already created a subscription to the topic?

Your question wasn't clear what your business logic in the code is.